# Movie about scientists building machine to drill down to the center of the earth's crust through a volcano

Tags: story-identification

There was a movie my late father had recorded, where they built a machine to drill down a volcano to the centre of the Earth's crust? Astronauts and scientists went on the mission. I remember a creepy world with a guy with long hair? They found another world.

The film was late 70s or 80s.

Not "[The Core](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298814/)" or "[Journey to the Center of the Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373051/?ref_=nv_sr_1)", more like a combo of the two?

Comment: Maybe you're think of At The Earth's Core? It doesn't match all of your details though. http://thestalkingmoon.weebly.com/the-stalking-moon/at-the-earths-core-1976

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtisticLicenseGeology

Answer (score 8):

This is a different '[Journey to the Centre of the Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107279/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_78)', from 1993 and featuring F. Murray Abraham, a pre-X-Files John Neville and pre-Voyager Tim Russ. I recall it's pretty dire and it's more like a feature-length pilot (that never got picked up) than a full movie.

The guy with long hair was some kind of subterranean being with, IIRC, some form of powers linked to a Macguffin that looked like a bit of circuitry, and I think there was intended to be some kind of meta-plot around rebuilding/reuniting the pieces of circuitry (one of the scientists on the ship, possibly John Neville, also had a piece). Presumably if it had been picked up for a series this would have been the overall arc plot.

Answer (score 2):

Movie: At the Earths Core.

http://manapop.com/film/filmreviews/at-the-earths-core-book-vs-movie/

it is from 1978. it may be one you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

Might it have been "Atragon"  a 1963 Japanese sci fi film?  It can be purchased on EBay or Amazon, they might have the theatrical trailer attached to verify.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F.  What about Atragon matches the description from the question?  Adding more detail will really improve this answer.